# How can I add a table in a theme using Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m building a site as part of my research using Word Press. I’m trying to display samples on the homepage in a neat way, something similar to this one http://www.maitrechoux.com/menu/index.html?categ_id=all .

I have removed all of the home function using remove_action. How can I add the table and then how can I add the pictures inside each cell? Is it only matter of CSS or do I need to add HTML code for this? I recently joined word press community and this is the only thing remained to complete my website.  Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

NO, don't use tables. I think what you actually want is just to display something that looks like table.

You need to code both html and css for that.

You can use any of popular css frameworks to help you out, or you can code it yourself using, flex, floats, or grid...

When you are done then with wp functions you need to render that data in your wp theme.

Your question is to broad and big to be answered via code snippets or examples, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nikola

I would love to code it myself and I would appreciate you or anyone's help. I will try to narrow it down. What I'm trying to do is I want my samples to be displayed the same way the referenced website did. Then I would like to have the lines/grid around it. I'm not too sure if this  made it narrower or easier to provide a code snippets. What else do you want me to provide to have my question answered?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to change the template of my WordPress [website](https://www.digi-follower.com/) and use React tables.

But this would cause my site to drop in Google rankings, and in terms of SEO, this would not be a good thing.

That's why I decided to use my template pre-built tables and change the files to my liking in the settings section by editing css files.